# Php can't start multiple sessions

Tags: php, session, startup, multiple-instances

I am trying to start 5 sessions one after the other, but if i try to start them all, no session gets created. It works only if i try to start the first one.

Code(PHP):

```
<?php
include_once("../scripts/session_start.php");
function generateRand()
{
    $characters = "QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNMqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm0123456789";
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $rand = "";
    for($i=0;$i<100;$i++)
    {
        $rand .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    return $rand;
}
$hCName = generateRand();
$_SESSION['hCName'] = $hCName;
$uCName = generateRand();
$_SESSION['uCName'] = $uCName;
$pCName = generateRand();
$_SESSION['pCName'] = $pCName;
$dNCName = generateRand();
$_SESSION['dNCName'] = $dNCName;
$dPCName = generateRand();
$_SESSION['dPCName'] = $dPCName;
?>
```

**Edit:**

Here is my session_start script(PHP):

```
<?php
if(file_exists("../parameters.php"))
{
    include_once("../parameters.php");
}
else
{
    include_once("parameters.php");
}
session_set_cookie_params(time()+600, "/", "localhost", $isSsl, true);
session_start();
session_regenerate_id(true);
?>
```

Comment: What do you mean no session is created? How do you check it ? I can see you're assigning 5 session variables, not starting 5 sessions.

Comment: Well, i have another php script, that tries to access the sessions. But it says undefined index to them all.

Comment: I'll assume you access it correctly. Nothing wrong with your code, you are assigning them correctly. The session cookie expiry is too long though.

Comment: i'd remove the `session_regenerate_id(true);` line - you don't need it and there appears to be unexpected behaviour using it.

Comment: Ok, so i found out, that i need to reload the page before the sessions get created...

Comment: These are not five sessions but five variables set in the session array. Show the php script where you see the undefined index

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<?php
session_start();
function generateRand()
{
    $characters = "QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNMqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm0123456789";
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $rand = "";
    for($i=0;$i<100;$i++)
    {
        $rand .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    return $rand;
}
$hCName = generateRand();
$_SESSION['hCName'] = $hCName;
$uCName = generateRand();
$_SESSION['uCName'] = $uCName;
$pCName = generateRand();
$_SESSION['pCName'] = $pCName;
$dNCName = generateRand();
$_SESSION['dNCName'] = $dNCName;
$dPCName = generateRand();
$_SESSION['dPCName'] = $dPCName;
?>
```

Comment: Ok, this works. But i want to use my own script, to create sessions more securely.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i found out, that the problem was caused by the fact, that i was creating 500 fake cookies to fool attackers. Apparently 500 is too much, because it stopped the sessions from creating. Sorry for not putting that cookie creation code.